# android chrome does not ask for geolocation permission if gps is disabled

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, gps

I am trying to get user's location by using html5 geolocation api.
(It is not for the native app)

It works find except the android device. The browsers and ios device shows info window which asking for the permission request. But android does not do that unless GPS is enabled. 
Anyone have resolved this issue ?

```
const options = { enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 100, timeout: 60000 }

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (success) {
    const crd = success.coords
    console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`)
    console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`)
    if (mapRef) {
      mapRef.panTo({
        lat: crd.latitude,
        lng: crd.longitude
      })
    }
  },
  function (failure) {
    if (failure.message.indexOf("Only secure origins are allowed") == 0) {
      // Secure Origin issue.
    }
  },
  options
)
```